# Selecting "ALL" and passing multiple values into Select Statement Parameter from DropDownList

Tags: sql, asp.net, visual-studio

So, I have a report that I am building the Visual Studio Express 2015 for Web.  I have a Select Statement to retrieve the data, using (3) parameters (@StartDate, @EndDate, @Equipment).  Stripping it down, the select statement looks like this:

```
Select * from Schedule
Where CAST(ScheduleDate as date) BETWEEN (@StartDate) AND @EndDate) AND 
EquipmentName IN (@Equipment)
```

So, in my DropDownList for @Equipment, say I have individual values such as:
MachineA, MachineB, MachineC.  All works well when I select an individual machine, however, I would like to add a selection called 'All'.  Via the DropDownList Tasks where I add the values, I added another item called 'All' with a value of 'MachineA','MachineB','MachineC', thinking this value would then be placed into the @Equipment parameter to be used in the IN condition.

Well, when I select 'All' from the dropdown, I don't get an error, but I also do not get any results.  I have confirmed at least within SSMS the syntax of the select statement is correct, so I suspect the value being passed in VS to the SQL query is not coming over in the correct format.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

Added Code of actual DropDownList.  The ListItem at the bottom called "ALL" is the item that it not translating into the IN condition of my select statement.

```
<h3 style="text-align: center">
            Equipment:
            <asp:DropDownList ID="EquipmentDownList1" runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="CARM1">CARM1</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="CT1">CT1</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="CT2">CT2</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="DEXA">DEXA</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="FL1">FL1</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="IR">IR</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="MAM1">MAM1</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="MAM2">MAM2</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="MRI1">MRI1</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="NM1">NM1</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="PET1">PET1</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="US1">US1</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="US2">US2</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="XR1">XR1</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="XR2">XR2</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="'CARM1','CT1','CT2','DEXA','FL1','IR','MAM1','MAM2','MRI1','NM1','PET1','US1','US2','XR1','XR2'">ALL</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
```

SQL: resname.ResourceDescription IN (@Equipment) is where I am having issues passing multiple values for @Equipment

```
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SHConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT 
                        CONVERT(varchar(10), app.ScheduledStartDtm, 101) AS 'Date', CONVERT(varchar(5), app.ScheduledStartDtm, 108) AS 'Start Time', CONVERT(varchar(5), app.ScheduledEndDtm, 108) AS 'End Time', visit.ClientDisplayName AS 'Client Name', visit.IDCode AS 'Client ID', 
                         visit.VisitIDCode AS 'Visit ID', loc.Name AS Location, event.EventName, provider.Name AS 'Ordering Provider', app.Comp AS 'Reason', '(' + hphone.AreaCode + ') ' + SUBSTRING(hphone.PhoneNumber, 0, 4) + '-' + SUBSTRING(hphone.PhoneNumber, 4, 4) AS 'Phone'
FROM            Appointment AS app INNER JOIN
                         ApptEvtResource AS equip ON equip.AppointmentID = app.AppointmentID INNER JOIN
                         Resource AS resname ON resname.ResourceID = equip.ResourceID INNER JOIN
                         Visit AS visit ON visit.GUID = app.ClientVisitGUID INNER JOIN
                         Provider AS provider ON provider.GUID = app.ProviderGUID INNER JOIN
                         Location AS loc ON loc.GUID = app.LocationGUID INNER JOIN
                         Event AS event ON event.EventID = app.EventID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         Phone AS hphone ON hphone.PersonGUID = visit.ClientGUID AND hphone.PhoneType = 'Home' AND hphone.Active = 'True'
WHERE       resname.ResourceDescription IN (@Equipment) AND (app.AppointmentStatus &lt;&gt; 'CANCELLED') AND CAST(app.ScheduledStartDtm as date) between @StartDate and @EndDate
ORDER BY 'Date','Start Time'">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="EquipmentDownList1" Name="Equipment" PropertyName="SelectedValue" DefaultValue="" />
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="StartDateBox" Name="StartDate" PropertyName="Text" />
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="EndDateBox" Name="EndDate" PropertyName="Text" />
            </SelectParameters>
```

Comment: Post the code please. How can we help without any code?  [Read this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Hey Rick, are you referring to the source code behind the aspx?

Comment: Minimal code behind would also be helpful to see how the query is being built and how your params are being passed.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you change the value for the ALL response to remove the single quotes.  Then modify your Where clause:

```
Select * from Schedule
Where CAST(ScheduleDate as date) BETWEEN (@StartDate) AND @EndDate)
AND EquipmentName like '%' + @Equipment + '%'
```

This assumes that none of the equipment names that are *not* on your list are a sub-string of equipment names that *are* on your list.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I do not believe that will work since I am wanting to actually pass all of the actual equipment names (MachineA, MachineB, MachineC) in the @Equipment for the IN condition.  Sorry if I wasn't clear, but I select 'All' from the dropdown, but the value attached to the 'All' is actually  'MachineA', 'MachineB', 'MachineC'.

Comment: Updated to match the value that you prefer.

Comment: Re-reading the edited question, I have reverted to the original snippet.  I am suggesting the you return the value "All" to your parameter.

Comment: Thank you Degan, but still no results.  I updated my original post with the actual code of the DropDownList.

Comment: OK.  I suspect that it might be the formatting of your All's ListItemValue.  Perhaps test with your selected statement modified to show the value for @Equipment.  (e.g. Select @Equipment)  That might illuminate the problem.

Comment: Degan, yeah I did that.  I ran the select statement in SSMS and placed all of the machines into the IN condition as if I were selecting all from the DropDownList (ex. ('CARM1', 'CT1', 'CT2',....) and it runs fine.  So yes, I do agree it is the formatting but I believe it is not crossing from the DropDownList correctly, even though I have the value for ALL set as I do if I were running a select statement in SSMS.

Comment: I think the issue may revolve around the single quotes?  When executing this via the query builder, I can put say CARM1 for the value of the @Equipment parameter and it works, however if I put 'CARM1', it will not.

Comment: @Zwick44, Yes, I agree it is the single quotes within the double quotes.  Why not try the return value, All?  What extra value does it add to have to supply the names of each individual machine?

Comment: That is a good question.  The reason I have to supply the name of the machines is because there are actually more machines than what I have listed.  I only need this to run for those selected machines.  I did get your suggestion (thanks again) to work above, but then I was getting additional records for machines that I do not want included.  I hope that makes sense.

Comment: You could also use CONTAINS.

Comment: Sorry, no go.  I changed to your adjustment above using the LIKE.  It will still give records for each individual selection, but not all.  I really appreciate your help on this!  I will continue to see what I can come up with.